# Regex on a Script

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am new to using Regex (about a week into it).

I have a hidden page on my site where I need to parse the following into lines to go inside of a Listbox:

```
DrillMagic.sbox.p50 && DrillMagic.sbox.p50(["drill",[["drills",0],["drill magic",0],["drill with a blog",0],["drill bits",0],["drill days are over florence and the machine",0],["drill white",0],["drill whistle",0],["drill wheel",0],["drill fails",0],["drill with a blog full episode",0]],{"j":"b","k":1,"q":"wFrM4x41L3IXuesFeKSW31gn7WQ"}])
```

I need all of the drill words in a variable string of lines like this:

```
drill
drills
drill magic
drill with a blog
drill bits
drill days are over florence and the machine
drill white
etc.
etc..
```

BUT, not all of my keywords are always going to contain "drill" within them.

Here's what I've come up with: `.+?` which I know is a VERY LAZY N GREEDY MATCH! LOL

I just need to grab the keywords from my script that are in this pattern, regardless of which random keywords they will be. Would appreciate the help...

Comment: `.` matches any character, so `.+?` will match the entire input.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: So what is the pattern you're looking for? Letters and spaces? Anything inside quotes?

Comment: What about `"j"` and `"b"`, are those keywords? If not, how should the pattern exclude them?

Comment: Hey Barmar! Thank you for helping me edit this post & your quick reply!

Comment: Here's the part that I'm trying to parse:  [["drills",0],["drill magic",0],["drill with a blog",0],["drill bits",0],["drill days are over florence and the machine",0],["drill white",0],["drill whistle",0],["drill wheel",0],["drill fails",0],["drill with a blog full episode",0]]

Comment: Edit the question, don't put it in a comment.

Comment: It doesn't make things clearer if you just say the same thing as the question.

Comment: All I need is just the keywords out of these pattern. If you scroll back to the top, you will see the entire pattern that I'm trying to parse. I need only all of the "drill" keywords in lines from top to bottom. I'm using VB.NET.

Comment: But you haven't told us how to tell what is a keyword and what isn't.

Comment: So I'm still getting a bunch of extra junk mixed in. the "j" and "b" aren't supposed to be included either for your last question.

Comment: Are you going to explain what the pattern is? You keep saying keywords, but that could be anything? If you can't explain it, you can't code it.

Comment: Why isn't the answer from @stribizhev good?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
"([^"]*)"(?=,[^\]]*\](?:,|\]))
```

It will capture into Group 1 the substrings that are inside double quotes, followed by a comma, then 0 or more symbols other than `]`, then `]` followed by `,` or `]`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQ6xS3/2)

Matches:

```
drill
drills
drill magic
drill with a blog
drill bits
drill days are over florence and the machine
drill white
drill whistle
drill wheel
drill fails
drill with a blog full episode
```

Comment: Hey Barmar, this is still pulling back a bunch of extras. Any other Regex ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Try `"([^"]*)"(?=,[^\]]*\](?:,|\]))`. Perhaps, the comma is the key here. And just FYI: I am not Barmar :)

Comment: Oooops!!! Sorry Stribizhev! I'm new here and noticed that Barmar was the one editing this post. He asked the first couple of questions in which I thought that I was still responding to him. BTW, thanks for your help/time! It seems to be working, but I'm going to test it out on a few more keywords and report back! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**Forget RegEx...** this is *[JSON](http://json.org/)*, or at least JSON with a few extra things in front. Just use one of the several JSON parsers available for .Net. [Newtonsoft's option](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is highly recommended and available via NuGet.